# REST API Accept header json/pdf

Tags: json, api, rest, pdf

I'm currently working with an API, which I would think is doing a wrong implementation of a REST API.

We have the following endpoints

1. GET v1/{organizationId}/invoices
2. GET v1/{organizationId}/invoices/{guid}

When you GET the first, you get all invoices, but if you get the second endpoint, without the `Accept: Application/json` header, you get the response from the first endpoint instead.

The company, which provides the API, says the reason for this is because the second endpoint can give both JSON and a PDF output, which would seem as a PDF would be

```
GET v1/{organizationId}/invoices/{guid}/pdf
```

Besides that, if send a malformed `guid`, you get a full blown HTML 404 error page instead of, e.g., a blank page or an error message.

To sum it up

1. Is the 2. endpoint handled properly?
2. Is it valid to make PDF an output like JSON/XML?
3. Shouldn't it be a new endpoint instead?
4. Is HTML allowed as an error response, even for a malformed request?

Comment: 4 sounds like the perfect place for returning Http Status Code 400 Bad Request

Comment: Hi, Can you pls share me the code snippet used for returning both json and pdf in the same method? We are having the exact same requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people don't like to categorize REST-based questions "right" and "wrong", but I will go ahead anyway:

1. No, the second resource should always return a representation of the second resource, that is, an invoice, never a collection of invoices.
2. Yes, it is completely OK to potentially return multiple representations of the same "thing". An invoice can conceivably return both json and pdf, and can select the correct one based on the "Accept" header.
3. No, it shouldn't be a new "endpoint", because these "things" are not "endpoints", but resources. An invoice is a resource, the json document is just a "representation" of the resource.
4. Yes, an error response can contain a body, with whatever representation the server is comfortable sending. The server should of course orient itself using the "Accept" header from the client, but is not required to do so.

A few remarks: It should not be possible to `GET` an invoice with a wrong *guid*, since these resources should be **linked** from the collection resource. When the client follows links (as it should), there should be no way to follow a link with a wrong guid.

It is wrong to return a completely different resource (invoice collection instead of an invoice), but it is OK to have multiple representations of the same resource. If there is no "Accept" header, the server should pick one, or indicate `406 Not Acceptable`.

One small point: The mime-type should not be `application/json`, because how do you know it's an invoice then? It should be something like: `application/vnd.someprovider.invoice+json`. No one bothers with mime-types these days, but I mention it just for completeness sake.